# Don't understand train data from convnetjs

Tags: javascript, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to predict some data using a neural network in javascript. For that I found [convnetjs](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/started.html) that seems easy to use.

In the example, they use one thing that they call MagicNet, so you don't need to know about NN to work with it. This is the example of use:

```
// toy data: two data points, one of class 0 and other of class 1
var train_data = [new convnetjs.Vol([1.3, 0.5]), new convnetjs.Vol([0.1, 0.7])];
var train_labels = [0, 1];

// create a magic net
var magicNet = new convnetjs.MagicNet(train_data, train_labels);
magicNet.onFinishBatch(finishedBatch); // set a callback a finished evaluation of a batch of networks

// start training MagicNet. Every call trains all candidates in current batch on one example
setInterval(function(){ magicNet.step() }, 0});

// once at least one batch of candidates is evaluated on all folds we can do prediction!
function finishedBatch() {
  // prediction example. xout is Vol of scores
  // there is also predict_soft(), which returns the full score volume for all labels
  var some_test_vol = new convnetjs.Vol([0.1, 0.2]);
  var predicted_label = magicNet.predict(some_test_vol);
}
```

What I don't understand is this:
They create train data like `[new convnetjs.Vol([1.3, 0.5]), new convnetjs.Vol([0.1, 0.7])]` and then use 2 labels. Those labels, are one for each position of array or for each element of subarray in those positions??

**Here is a visual example:**

It's like `[new 0, new 1]` or like `[new convnetjs.Vol([0, 1]), new convnetjs.Vol([0, 1])]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample `new convnetjs.Vol([1.3, 0.5])` has label `0`.

The sample `new convnetjs.Vol([0.1, 0.7])` has label `1`.

In general, in machine learning, you'd usually have samples which can be quite high-dimensional (here they are only two-dimensional), but you'd have a single label per sample which tells you which "class" it belongs in. What the classes actually mean depends on the problem you are trying to solve; for instance, they could be the digits that are represented by images of hand-written digits.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my question. Just one more thing; if I have 8 lavels and I want to predict the 8th one... How could I do it? (Boolean value: 0-1)

Comment: @Sascuash: The `magicNet.predict(some_test_vol)` does prediction of the label for some given input.